# Removing ViewController in Navigation Stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

In navigation stack , i am having 6 view controllers 
like
A->B->C->D->E->F

At the view controller **F**, I want to go back to the view controller **B**, how can I do this? I want to remove the view controllers one by one. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: [look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027559/can-i-pop-to-specific-viewcontroller)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[B class]])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pop directly to B Class ViewController then try following.

```
for (UIViewController *VC in [self.navigationController viewControllers])
{
    // here B is ViewCotroller Class Name
    if ([VC isKindOfClass:[B class]])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:VC animated:TRUE];
        break;
    }
}
```

`[self.navigationController viewControllers]` returns the array of ViewControllers of current navigation stack. I used `For` (each) loop to find out our view controller (which is B ViewController) from array. If it is match than We will perform the Pop operation to that ViewController.

Comment: Right answer mahesh.

Comment: @balkaransingh yes i am and you too. but lets see what Agal Sivamanoj want.

Comment: @thanks Mahesh and balkaransingh , after popped i want to clear all the data.example , after poping i am having one image on that view controller i want to clear that after popped ,

Comment: in which ViewController you want to clear image? i mean in F ViewController or B ViewController? @AgalSivamanoj

Comment: @Mahesh, I want to clear the image after moving from f to b viewcontroller .i want to clear the image in b view controller

Comment: To do so you need to check condition in `ViewDidAppear` method of B that we are coming from F. Take boolean as Property in B and make it true when we push to C. in `ViewDidAppear` check that if bool is true than clear image and change bool to false.

Comment: You need to ask this in question so i can write solution in answer. @AgalSivamanoj

Answer (score 0):

You can use responder chain to reach to your targetVC and pop the ones above it.

Comment: If you want to clear data in that view controller, you need to have your own function which resets your VC manually.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments Rin and Kirandeep Kumar  , i have tried like this ,it is working now

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

But i want to remove all the data in that view controller i.e objectAtindex:1
Please share how to do this 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is , for removing the viewcontroller we able to use notification also

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"new" object:nil];
```

i have posted the notification in fVC and in BVC i registered and observed the notification and that method i removes the viewcontroller and clear that data

Answer (score -2):

Try it:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:vcB animated:Yes];
```