# Going form 1 viewcontroller to another

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, viewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers: VC1,VC2, VC3.
The navigation is made pushing viewcontrollers (forward) like this: VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3.
Now once I an in VC3, pressing a button I want to go back to VC1 (not VC2).
If I use a pop I'd go into VC2, but how would I go directly from VC3 into VC1? (Like poping twice...)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you want is an `popToViewController:`.

Take a look a this solution: [Can i pop to Specific ViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027559/can-i-pop-to-specific-viewcontroller)

Comment: Or use `popToRootViewController:`.

Comment: Right, but you don't necessarily want to go to the root one. In the OP's case, yes, but it's also a good alternative.